# "\n" is getting removed from grep output while setting to a variable

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a following file

```
A Query 3 ms
B Query 4 ms 
A Query 5 ms
```

I have written grep command to extract the path I required.

```
temp=`grep A acces.log | grep Query `
```

Putting that in temp variable is removing "\n" from the output. 
How to force bash not to remove \n ?

Sorry for my bad communication 
I am getting following o/p like

```
A Query 3 ms A query 5 ms
```

I need o/p in following format

```
 A Query 3 ms
 A query 5 ms
```

Comment: @CarlNorum I want to parse that o/p using two awk script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need use double quotes:

```
temp=`grep A acces.log | grep Query `
echo "$temp"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll echo @Carl's question: why do you need it to be in the variable?  Most uses I can think of for something like this make it either unnecessary or easy to add back later.  But if you really need to preserve it, the best way I know of is to add a protective extra line to the command's output, and then remove it *after* the output has been stored in a variable:

```
temp=$(grep A acces.log | grep Query; echo x)
temp="${temp%x}"
```

The `echo` command actually adds "x" and *another* newline, but that extra newline gets removed by the `$()` replacement so all that needs to be removed explicitly is the "x".

Comment: Sorry for my bad communication skills. I had updated my question.